# Rewrite Rule is not working

Tags: apache

I started experimenting with rewrite rules in .htaccess file. I am trying to change the url using RewriteRule but unable to accomplish it.
Need to get contents from 
 `user.php?user=3&name=xyz` when `user.php/xyz` is accessed
user=anydigit and name=anyname

The current code which i am using is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/user.php/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /user.php?user=$1&name=$2 
</IfModule>
```

When i use the above code nothing is happening.

Comment: And have you looked at the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are accessing wrong page. rules on .htaccess says you should access a url like `user.php/3/xyz` instead of `user.php/xyz`

Comment: i even tried accessing `user.php/3/xyz`, even then i am not getting the desired output

Comment: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?user=$1&name=$2` try this one